# Attach a new unique ID if grouped delta > 5 seconds

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, timedelta

I would like to attach new IDs to my current groups (id column), based on the grouped delta, which indicates how long the group (id column) did not appear in the data frame. If the delta is more than 5 (seconds), I would like to attach a new ID to my IDs, as shown in the "expected_id" column. The new ID should be unique.

Any advice on how to do this?

Here is my data (df):

```
id  datetime                    delta       expected_id
1   2023-12-04 15:26:47.059800  1.439766    1
1   2023-12-04 15:26:48.493609  1.433809    1
1   2023-12-04 15:26:49.890176  1.396567    1
1   2023-12-04 15:26:51.274575  1.384399    1
2   2023-12-04 15:26:51.274575  169.15666   2
1   2023-12-04 15:26:52.715784  1.441209    1
1   2023-12-04 15:26:54.288126  1.572342    1
2   2023-12-04 15:26:54.288126  3.013551    2
1   2023-12-04 15:26:55.802795  1.514669    1
2   2023-12-04 15:26:55.802795  1.514669    2
1   2023-12-04 15:26:57.189969  1.387174    1
2   2023-12-04 15:26:57.189969  1.387174    2
1   2023-12-04 15:26:58.552681  1.362712    1
1   2023-12-04 15:27:00.005263  1.452582    1
2   2023-12-04 15:27:00.005263  2.815294    2
3   2023-12-04 15:27:00.005263  nan         3
1   2023-12-04 15:27:01.378002  1.372739    1
2   2023-12-04 15:27:01.378002  1.372739    2
1   2023-12-04 15:27:02.758197  1.380195    1
1   2023-12-04 15:27:04.165050  1.406853    1
1   2023-12-04 15:27:05.562082  1.397032    1
1   2023-12-04 15:27:06.953888  1.391806    1
1   2023-12-04 15:27:08.365109  1.411221    1
1   2023-12-04 15:27:09.737913  1.372804    1
1   2023-12-04 15:27:11.295586  1.557673    1
2   2023-12-04 15:27:11.295586  9.917584    4
1   2023-12-04 15:27:12.817794  1.522208    1
1   2023-12-04 15:27:14.337981  1.520187    1 
1   2023-12-04 15:27:15.811874  1.473893    1
1   2023-12-04 15:27:17.318122  1.506248    1 
2   2023-12-04 15:27:17.318122  6.022536    5
3   2023-12-04 15:27:17.318122  17.312859   6
4   2023-12-04 15:27:17.318122  nan         7
5   2023-12-04 15:27:17.318122  nan         8
6   2023-12-04 15:27:17.318122  nan         9
1   2023-12-04 15:27:18.808131  1.490009    1
2   2023-12-04 15:27:18.808131  1.490009    5
3   2023-12-04 15:27:18.808131  1.490009    6
4   2023-12-04 15:27:18.808131  1.490009    7
5   2023-12-04 15:27:18.808131  1.490009    8
6   2023-12-04 15:27:18.808131  1.490009    9
1   2023-12-04 15:27:20.189021  1.38089     1
2   2023-12-04 15:27:20.189021  1.38089     5
3   2023-12-04 15:27:20.189021  1.38089     6
4   2023-12-04 15:27:20.189021  1.38089     7
5   2023-12-04 15:27:20.189021  1.38089     8
6   2023-12-04 15:27:20.189021  1.38089     9
1   2023-12-04 15:27:21.618110  1.429089    1
1   2023-12-04 15:27:23.099324  1.481214    1
2   2023-12-04 15:27:23.099324  2.910303    5
```

The delta column I achieve with this:

```
df['delta'] = df.groupby("id")['datetime'].diff() / np.timedelta64(1, 's')
```

How to create my "expected_id" column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, you need to just convert the `id` to the new expected id like this:

```py
df["new_expected_id"] = (df["id"] != df["id"].shift()).cumsum() - 1
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    id                   datetime  delta  expected_id  new_expected_id
0    0 2023-12-04 10:51:30.158743    NaN            0                0
1    1 2023-12-04 10:51:31.734037    NaN            1                1
2    1 2023-12-04 10:51:33.219067   1.48            1                1
3    1 2023-12-04 10:51:34.469723   1.25            1                1
4    0 2023-12-04 10:51:35.862997   5.70            2                2
5    0 2023-12-04 10:51:37.280209   1.41            2                2
6    0 2023-12-04 10:51:38.741301   1.46            2                2
7    0 2023-12-04 10:51:40.239296   1.49            2                2
8    1 2023-12-04 10:51:41.590683   7.12            3                3
9    1 2023-12-04 10:51:43.060751   1.47            3                3
10   1 2023-12-04 10:51:44.566724   1.50            3                3
11   1 2023-12-04 10:51:46.066713   1.49            3                3
12   0 2023-12-04 10:51:47.493897   7.25            4                4
13   0 2023-12-04 10:51:48.994885   1.50            4                4
14   0 2023-12-04 10:51:50.557707   1.56            4                4
15   0 2023-12-04 10:51:52.116537   1.55            4                4
16   0 2023-12-04 10:51:53.642456   1.52            4                4
17   1 2023-12-04 10:51:55.115518   9.04            5                5
```

---

EDIT 2: With the new input:

```py
from itertools import count


def fn(g, cnt):
    x = next(cnt)
    mask = g["datetime"].diff() >= "5s"
    g.loc[mask, "expected_id"] = np.array([next(cnt) for _ in range(mask.sum())])
    g["expected_id"] = g["expected_id"].ffill()
    g["expected_id"] = g["expected_id"].fillna(x).astype(int)
    return g


c = count(1)
out = df.groupby("id", group_keys=False, sort=False).apply(fn, cnt=c)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
    id                   datetime       delta  expected_id
0    1 2023-12-04 15:26:47.059800    1.439766            1
1    1 2023-12-04 15:26:48.493609    1.433809            1
2    1 2023-12-04 15:26:49.890176    1.396567            1
3    1 2023-12-04 15:26:51.274575    1.384399            1
4    2 2023-12-04 15:26:51.274575  169.156660            2
5    1 2023-12-04 15:26:52.715784    1.441209            1
6    1 2023-12-04 15:26:54.288126    1.572342            1
7    2 2023-12-04 15:26:54.288126    3.013551            2
8    1 2023-12-04 15:26:55.802795    1.514669            1
9    2 2023-12-04 15:26:55.802795    1.514669            2
10   1 2023-12-04 15:26:57.189969    1.387174            1
11   2 2023-12-04 15:26:57.189969    1.387174            2
12   1 2023-12-04 15:26:58.552681    1.362712            1
13   1 2023-12-04 15:27:00.005263    1.452582            1
14   2 2023-12-04 15:27:00.005263    2.815294            2
15   3 2023-12-04 15:27:00.005263         NaN            3
16   1 2023-12-04 15:27:01.378002    1.372739            1
17   2 2023-12-04 15:27:01.378002    1.372739            2
18   1 2023-12-04 15:27:02.758197    1.380195            1
19   1 2023-12-04 15:27:04.165050    1.406853            1
20   1 2023-12-04 15:27:05.562082    1.397032            1
21   1 2023-12-04 15:27:06.953888    1.391806            1
22   1 2023-12-04 15:27:08.365109    1.411221            1
23   1 2023-12-04 15:27:09.737913    1.372804            1
24   1 2023-12-04 15:27:11.295586    1.557673            1
25   2 2023-12-04 15:27:11.295586    9.917584            3
26   1 2023-12-04 15:27:12.817794    1.522208            1
27   1 2023-12-04 15:27:14.337981    1.520187            1
28   1 2023-12-04 15:27:15.811874    1.473893            1
29   1 2023-12-04 15:27:17.318122    1.506248            1
30   2 2023-12-04 15:27:17.318122    6.022536            4
31   3 2023-12-04 15:27:17.318122   17.312859            6
32   4 2023-12-04 15:27:17.318122         NaN            7
33   5 2023-12-04 15:27:17.318122         NaN            8
34   6 2023-12-04 15:27:17.318122         NaN            9
35   1 2023-12-04 15:27:18.808131    1.490009            1
36   2 2023-12-04 15:27:18.808131    1.490009            5
37   3 2023-12-04 15:27:18.808131    1.490009            6
38   4 2023-12-04 15:27:18.808131    1.490009            7
39   5 2023-12-04 15:27:18.808131    1.490009            8
40   6 2023-12-04 15:27:18.808131    1.490009            9
41   1 2023-12-04 15:27:20.189021    1.380890            1
42   2 2023-12-04 15:27:20.189021    1.380890            5
43   3 2023-12-04 15:27:20.189021    1.380890            6
44   4 2023-12-04 15:27:20.189021    1.380890            7
45   5 2023-12-04 15:27:20.189021    1.380890            8
46   6 2023-12-04 15:27:20.189021    1.380890            9
47   1 2023-12-04 15:27:21.618110    1.429089            1
48   1 2023-12-04 15:27:23.099324    1.481214            1
49   2 2023-12-04 15:27:23.099324    2.910303            5
```

Comment: Thank you so much Andrej, this brought me a bit further. The only thing that is missing is to include the delta column to only cumsum() if delta is > 5. If its more than 5, it should get a new id, if its under 5 it should keep the same ID. Any suggestion?

Comment: @kkjjnn Can you clarify what columns do you have in your initial dataframe? Do you have only `id` and `datetime` columns?

Comment: yes, I have only the id and datetime, and from that I create the delta column like this: df['delta'] = df.groupby("id")['datetime'].diff() / np.timedelta64(1, 's'), so that I know if the ID was present in the last 5 seconds. If not, I would like to do the cumsum like you did. If yes, it should just keep its original id. Does that make sense?

Comment: @kkjjnn I've updated my answer, I hope that's what you mean by *to include the delta column to only cumsum() if delta is > 5*.

Comment: Unfortunately the id still gets a new id, even if the id occurred less than 5 seconds earlier. I'll add some more data in this post, to understand better.

Comment: So sorry for the confusion. So with the new data you see that id 1 stays id 1 throughout, because it occurs throughout the dataset with a delta always less than 5 seconds. In contrast, id 2 for example gets 4 at some point, because it was missing for more than 5 seconds. Should i open a new post? Or do you think we can solve it, or is it still unclear? I feel we are so close.

Comment: @kkjjnn I've updated my answer.

Comment: You are amazing. I appreciate that very much!